# Is there any way to "save" a disconnected RDP sesion's state in a manner analogous to ACPI hibernate for a regular PC?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services, hibernate, acpi

Related to: [How often do you restart a heavily-utilized Windows Server 2008R2 Remote Desktop Server (VM)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/691568/how-often-do-you-restart-a-heavily-utilized-windows-server-2008r2-remote-desktop)

If there are some disconnected user sessions on a Windows Server 2008R2 or Windows Server 2012R2 Remote Desktop Server, is there any way to persist them to a file - as the "hibernate" function does - so that users' unsaved files and application states may survive the reboot? I am open to built-in as well as third-party solutions.

If there is not a way to do this, do you think it is because of the perceived lack-of-need for such a function, or rather some insurpassable technical hurdle to its implementation?

Comment: I'd think it's technical, or how people expect reboot to be. Reboot should  bring a server back to a *clean* status. If the server is to bring back user sessions after reboot, it could put the server back to "dirty" status again that caused the reboot in the first place.

Comment: I read your other post and felt that you are going for wrong direction. As others pointed out, talk to management, set their and users expectation properly, then have an auto log off in place. You'd be surprised how quickly people adapt to it. Chances are you end up having happier clients.

Comment: @strongline to be clear, I plan on implementing the suggestion of automatic reboots and setting expectations. In the best case, this would be end of the story. However, if this kind of tool existed, it would be nice if I could at least make a "best effort" at saving any disconnected sessions prior to reboot to pacify those users who did not log off

Comment: This is heavy to implement, you will probably fall from one problem to another. One idea that comes in my mind is use virtual machines for remote users, depending of how many remote users you have - because this is very not optimal solution. So where server reboot vm gets hibernated. But someone who was working on vm, probably was using networked software, and depending of software in your company, it will or not crash after lost connection to eg. SQL server. So you should start searching and checking for solution from application side, check how it will behave after network disconnection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible with the default tools.  The best way to solve the problem of users continuing to log on is to enable drain mode on the server.  You can then send a warning to the users as they log in to the disconnected sessions to re-login, and they will get directed to the second TS in the farm.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the drain mode. That's a great idea.